# Do records with the same key in two RDDs repartitioned by key reside in the same node in spark?

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, apache-spark, parallel

I have two RDDs named "**data**" and "**model**", they are repartitioned by key described as below :
[image]

**Does the tuple records with the same key reside in the same node in my cluster ?**

**Should it save IO cost in shuffle operation, such as "*data.cogroup(model)*" , if it comes true ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tuple of one partition is always on the same node because a partition itself is impartible. So if you do a `groupBy` or write your own partitioner which partitions by key, all records with the same key/partition number will be shuffled to the same node.

Otherwise, transformations like [mapPartition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741714/how-does-the-pyspark-mappartitions-function-work) which pass an iterator to a user defined function wouldn't work.